# getExistingDirectory stuck in runtime but not in debugger

Tags: python, pyqt, dialog

In python, I'm using
'''
QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory
'''

to call the select directory dialogue box. When running the GUI, it gets stuck when i call this line. In debug mode, it runs perfectly and promptly.
The code is:

```
import time
import numpy as np
import csv
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import sys
import GUI

class EdgeMeasuringApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, GUI.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
         super(EdgeMeasuringApp, self).__init__(parent)
         self.setupUi(self)

        # path = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'select directory', directory='C:\\')

        self.BrowseButton.clicked.connect(self.setPath)


    def setPath(self):
        path = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, 'select directory',directory='C:\\')
        try:
            self.SaveToEdit.setText(path)
        except:
            self.StatusEdit.setText('Directory not set!')

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = EdgeMeasuringApp()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The GUI itself is generated in PyQt designer. I then transform it to a .py file through the appropriate CMD command.

The grayed out command in the init of the class actually works, but when i put it in any of the functions in the code, i get the same behavior.

I've tried giving it a different directory to look into, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Using Windows 10. Pycharm 2020.2.3. Python 3.8. PyQt5.15.4.

What could cause such peculiar behavior?

Comment: What do you mean by "gets stuck"? Does it show the dialog? Does it show the contents of the directory? How are you running it? What OS are you using?

Comment: Dialogue isn't shown. GUI simply becomes completely unresponsive. Running via Pycharm interface. Answered the OS and Python version in question body.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I've recreated a QTdesigner app with just the Browse button and a line edit, and now it works well. However, this is a standalone call in my code anyway, so I don't know how to make a minimal reproducable example without revealing more sensitive parts of this GUI

Comment: You don't have to reveal anything, just try to reduce the code by removing parts that are not (or do not seem to be) related to the problem, and constantly check if the problem still occurs. As soon as it doesn't anymore, you've probably found the culprit, so you could try to remove *other* parts if you still don't understand the reason, so that you'll have an actual MRE.

Comment: I've edit the question so that the MRC is there.